# Is using the MSVCC extension keyword "abstract" after a class name a good practice?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider following example:

```
class CBase abstract
{
protected:
    CBase() { }
};
```

I could get rid either of the **protected constructor** or the '**abstract**' keyword. The keyword is intuitive to use, but as far as I know, it isn't supported by other compilers (especially Gcc).

I was also wondering if using some kind of macro to prepare this code for g++ compilation would be easy enough to write. I want to minimalize code changes if I ever wanted to compile my code on system other than MS Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a pure virtual destructor with an empty definition, i.e.

```
class CBase {
public:
  virtual ~CBase() = 0;
}

inline CBase::~CBase() {}
```

Any not-even-decent C++ compiler supports this and the standard allows it.

Comment: I heard that adding pure virtual destructors causes unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The compiler will probably optimize the empty definition out completely (i.e. it won't be called at all).

Comment: @Bartek: Have you measured it?

Comment: It _does_ cause overhead. In particular, it causes a vtable to be created, and adds a vptr (on MSVC/GCC). The empty dtor will be inlined in derived dtors (that's trivial), but probably not removed (hard to prove that's OK).

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but you don't know whether the overhead is significant in your case unless you measure.

Answer (score 1):

A macro would be trivial: `#define abstract`. The keyword doesn't add functionality.

Comment: but what about pure virtual methods where abstract keyword is also used?